# I need to disable submit button until all the fields are having values

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable submit button until all the fields are having values.
I have seen few examples having  tags. But here I am using @Html.TextBoxFor. I have tried out something after referring to few examples online. But I am still unable to achieve the expected result. Any help please ?

Here is my html code:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("User", "Plan"))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <p id="myElem" style="display:none; font-style:italic;background-color:yellow">Floor Plan Saved Successfully</p>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Period:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Quarter", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q1", Value = "1" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q2", Value = "2" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q3", Value = "3" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q4", Value = "4" }) }, "-- Select Quarter --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2016", Value = "2016" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }) }, "-- Select Year --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Line ID:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.floorConfig.LineID, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-4" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Clear" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
```

Below is the script i have written to disable the submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Quarter, #Year, #LineID").keyup(function () {
        $(".submit").attr('disabled', $(this).val() && $(this).val() != "-- Select Quarter --" && $(this).val() != "-- Select Year --" ? "" : 'disabled');
    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Why? Just add validation attributes to your properties and enable client side validation so that if the form is not valid then the error messages are displayed and the submit will be cancelled

Comment: can you please give me some example code? Thanks

Comment: [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Quarter, #Year, #LineID").keyup(function () {
    $(".submit").prop("disabled", !$("#Quarter").val() || !$("#Year").val() || !$("#LineID").val());
});
```

$("#someId").val() is false if its value is null, so it will make the value of the attribute "disabled" to true.

In case you don't know,

```
$(this).val() ? "" : "disable")
```

is an internal if/else. It basically means the same as

```
if( $(this).val()){ // if this has a value not null or empty
//"disable" attribute takes "" as value
}else{
//"disable" attribute takes "disable" as value
}
```

I hope it will work. If not, it means that JS considers your dropdownlist basic selection as a value, so you have more checks to do between $(this).val() and the question mark, like

```
$("#Quarter, #Year, #LineID").keyup(function () {
    $(".submit").prop("disabled", !$("#Quarter").val() || !$("#Year").val() || !$("#LineID").val() || $("#Quarter").val() == "-- Select Quarter --" || $("#Year").val() == "-- Select Year --");
    });
```

Comment: I have even updated my question with the code changes. The submit button is still not getting disabled.

Comment: usually, when it comes to checkboxes or select, attr may not work, so use prop instead like : $(".myCheckbox").prop("checked", true) for example. It even works with the input readonly like $("#someInput").prop("readonly", false)

Comment: so $("#Quarter, #Year, #LineID").keyup(function () {
        $(".submit").prop("disabled", !$("#Quarter").val() || !$("#Year").val() || !$("#LineID").val());
        });
It should work. If not, you can add some other OR like :  || $("#Quarter").val()  == "-- Select Quarter --"

Comment: I have edited my answer. The last code should definitely work I think ^^